# How to log and parse InputStream in Android

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I parse an InputStream with following code and it works fine.

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
XmlHandlerMatchDetails handler = new XmlHandlerDetails();
xr.setContentHandler(handler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(data));
```

Now I need to log the InputStream to check it, I change the previous code in this way:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
XmlHandlerMatchDetails handler = new XmlHandlerDetails();
xr.setContentHandler(handler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(data));

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data)); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
String line; 
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {     
   sb.append(line); 
} 
String text = sb.toString();
Log.i(mTag, text);
```

But I have the error

09-19 12:13:02.982: ERROR/MyClass(338): java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.

How it's possible to log or to convert the stream to string without close it?

**EDIT - SOLVED!!!**

I solve it parsing the string instead of InputStream

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(text)));
```

Comment: maybe this solution may be helpful for somebody: http://shomeser.blogspot.com/2013/12/redirect-stream-to-logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the problem, but you could try re-writing your while loop to this:

```
while( br.ready() )
  sb.append( br.readLine() );
```

Another thing that pops to my mind, is that the InputStream you use (data), might not be able to be read twice - thus parsing it with the XmlReader first causes it to close and then it will not be open when you try to parse it with the BufferedReader. To verify this, try to run the BufferedReader without first parsing the data with the XmlReader.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the parsing seems to close the InputStream. Also if I first log the InputStream and then try to parse there is the same problem. Only parsing or only logging no problems

Comment: What do you need the log for? You should be able to retrieve all the data from the XmlReader after parsing.

Comment: I want to check and read the XML file that application download. I solve the issue (first post edited) first I convert the InputStream to string, then I log the string and parse it instead of InputStream.